# Cannot unmarshall a json array in golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I currently have a json array that looks like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo", 
    "age": "12",
    "id": "12"
  },
  {
    "name": "foo", 
    "age": "12",
    "id": "12"
  }
]
```

Now the above is a json array. The object I have for the above is

```
type CustType struct {
    Name          string      `json:"name"`
    Age           string      `json:"age"`
}
```

However to unmarshal from an array to struct I created this

```
type CustTypes struct {
    MyTypes []CustType
}
```

then I am doing this

```
e := CustTypes{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &e)
```

However I am not getting anything unmarshalled. Any idea what I might be doing wrong ? I did skip the field `id` in the struct but I believe that does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your errors:

```
err = json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.CustTypes
```

The problem is that you're trying to unmarshal an array into an object.  Unmarshal directly into `MyTypes`.

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &e.MyTypes)
```

I get the following when using `fmt.Printf`:

```
e = {MyTypes:[{Name:foo Age:12} {Name:foo Age:12}]}
```